# Will random pick unique row in csv in each thread in Gatling Scala

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling, web-api-testing, scala-gatling

I'm using random method in Gatling Scala to pick a row in feed. When I run this over for multiple threads, will each thread be picking unique row from the csv?

```
feed(csv("data.csv").random)
```

And within a thread, If I call the random function multiple times, will the returned row be unique?

Given - I have a huge number of rows, compared to the numbers of times I get a row.

Answer (score 1):

No. That's what [shuffle](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/feeder/#strategies) is for.